# Align controls correctly when using ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, itemscontrol

Can someone tell me how to align and resize controls correctly when using the `ItemsControl`.

I want to have a description on the left and a `TextBox` on the right for multiple fields which are defined in an `ObservableCollection` to end up with something like:

```
First Name:    [FirstNameTextBox]
Last Name:     [LastNameTextBox]
Date of Birth: [DobTextBox]
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
First Name: [FirstNameTextBox]
Last Name: [LastNameTextBox]
Date of Birth: [DobTextBox]
```

I want all the textbox to be aligned based on the largest `<TextBlock>`. If this was done directly in a `<Grid>` control, it would be straight forward as all controls are directly in the grid and you would just have the following columns definition defined

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I thought I could use the `SharedSizeGroup` property in the `<Grid>` but it still doesn't resize correctly. Instead it only displays the `<TextBlock>` stretch across the `<Grid>`.

Here's my code:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Labels" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="InputControls" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTemplate.Fields}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="InputControls"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE1:** I cannot get this to work as I need it to. This is what I've got so far:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Purple">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="Overall" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="InputControls" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTemplate.Fields}"                               
                  Background="Yellow" 
                  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Green">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="InputControls"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Margin="5"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             Margin="5"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

This ends up displaying my layout this way:

[image]

As you can see, my `TextBox` are correctly aligned based on the largest `TextBlock` but my ItemsControls is not stretched all the way across. I guess that makes sense as it is within the same grid where the `ColumnDefinitions` are defined.

Now, if I move the `ColumnDefinitions' out this grid to the outer grid and remove all instances of`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`, I guess the following:

[image]

Which once again is closer to what I need as my ItemsControl is now stretching all the way as I've set its `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` and my `TextBox` are still aligned to the `TextBlock` and are stretching all the way across but the problem now is that the `TextBlock` should be smaller as the Column is set to `Auto` but they appear to behave as if the column was set to `*` and I guess I'm losing the purpose of using `IsSharedSizeScope` since it has been removed.

Now if I add `IsSharedSizeScope="True"` to the outer grid, I get the following result:

[image]

Again, this is close to what I want as my ItemsControl is stretched, my textboxes are also stretch but they are no longer aligned to the largest `TextBlock`.

Finally, if I add `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` to `ItemsControl` as originally suggested by @mm8,

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Purple" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels" Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="InputControls" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTemplate.Fields}"                               
                      Background="Yellow" 
                      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Green">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="InputControls"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Margin="5"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             Margin="5"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>

    <!--<TextBlock Text="Invoice Number" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="InvoiceNumber" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
</Grid>
```

I get the following:

[image]

Which brings me back to square one, though the definitions are different?

**I need to achieve the following:**

[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: `ListView` would give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` property of the `ItemsControl` itself:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBarcodeTemplate.Fields}" 
              Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

**Synchronizing the width of elements in an ItemsControl:** https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/09/06/synchronizing-the-width-of-elements-in-an-itemscontrol/

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: Hi @mm8, I was too quick accepting the answer it partially fixed my problem. It now aligns my `TextBoxes` based on the longest `TextBlock` correctly but it doesn't stretch them all the way across the `ItemsControl`. I've tried different scenario but can't get them to stretch. I'm obviously missing something else. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What TextBox do you want to stretch?

Comment: If you want this to stretch to fill the ItemsControl there is no reason to use a SharedSizeGroup for it: <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I've updated my answer which hopefully will highlight the problem, wherever it may be. Hopefully you can help. Thanks.

Comment: "I get the following" looks fine to me. What do you want?

Comment: I want my left column to be auto-sized (auto) based on the largest 'TextBlock' i.e. Document Number in this instance and I want to my right column to use the remaining space (*) and I need my textboxes to stretch all the way. I've updated the question with a new snapshot showing what I want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Not to worry. I found the answer on WPF Tutorial and posted it as an answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Did you miss my comment about the <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> above?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer in the following article: [WPF Tutorial - Grid Panel](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) under the section: "How to share the width of a column over multiple grids".

As per article:

> Columns and rows that participate in size-sharing do not respect Star sizing. In the size-sharing scenario, Star sizing is treated as Auto. Since TextWrapping on TextBlocks within an SharedSize column does not work you can exclude your last column from the shared size. This often helps to resolve the problem.

So my final `XAML` looks like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Purple" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="InputControls" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBarcodeTemplate.Fields}"
                  Background="Yellow"
                  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Green" ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Margin="5"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             Margin="5"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

And the outcome now finally looks correct:

[image]

Hope this helps others!